# Why doesn't Directive work with some settings (e.g. Arrowheads) for VectorStyle?

Tags: plotting

In Mathematica 10 on two different Windows machines, `VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorStyle -> "Segment"]` works just fine, but `VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorStyle -> Directive["Segment"]]` or anything more complicated seems to ignore the named setting for `VectorStyle`.

Thinking it was an issue with named settings only, I tried `VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]` which doesn't work even though it works without the `Directive`. For the record, `Directive` works just fine in other contexts, like `VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0], FrameStyle -> Directive[16]]`

1. Is this a bug?
2. How can I get around this to get black segments in my `VectorPlot`?

Comment: I confirm that `VectorStyle -> Directive[Arrowheads[0]]` doesn't work. On Mathematica 10.0.2 for Mac here.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get ...  black segments in my VectorPlot?

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  VectorStyle -> {{Black, "Segment"}}]
```

[image]